# Displaying value in tooltip from function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I want to simply display a parameter value from a jQuery tooltip function
here is my code for it

```
that.SampleToolTip = function (iOaCount, iObCount,iTotalCount) {
    $("#assignment").hover(function () {
        if (iTotalCount != 0) {
            var count = 0;
            $("#assignment").attr('title' + iOaCount+'This is the hover-over text');

        }
    });          
}
```

Here, if I simply display line 'title' then it is displayed in tooltip but not the function parameters. When I display function parameter then tooltip is not displayed. 
I tried this also:

```
var count=icount;
```

and then displaying count in tooltip but it didn't work.

Comment: finally,after many trials got the answer it should be

    $("#assignment").attr('title','This is the hover-over text'+iOaCount+'\nwhatever');
Someone with more than 10 reputation plz post it as answer as it may help others.
      
As,the title is tile of tooltip which is to be given and after comma is the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not setting the title attribute but getting a value of attribute with name:
'title' + iOaCount+'This is the hover-over text'

you are missing a comma. change you code to:

```
  $("#assignment").attr('title', iOaCount + 'This is the hover-over text');
```

if the function is used with one parameter then it retrieves the attribute value.
if with two parameters than it sets the value of the attribute with the second parameter.

You can see that in jquery documenation: [jquery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)